# kendo upload widget with custom file browser

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, upload

Is it possible to create a custom file browser and append files to the kendo upload widget for async upload?

I've created a custom file browser to select files for upload, however I am not able to push the files into the FileList array object of the input element. Is there a way I can programmatically fire the select and upload file events for the Kendo upload?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
 $(".k-upload-selected").click();
```

Comment: Yes and it unfortunately has not worked out for me. I am following this tutorial from Kendo: http://dojo.telerik.com/@d.madjarov/AvOQa/11. I manage to push file information (name, size, extension) into the list wrapper, however the kendo upload widget does not treat the entries from the custom file browser as file inputs.